# Как правильно упорядочить данные по сумме полей из другой таблицы?

Tags: sql, postgresql

У таблицы `games` есть `counters` (счетчики). Их может быть несколько. у счетчиков есть поле `sent:bigint`.
Как отсортировать игры по порядку по кол-во этих отправленных (`sent`) счетчиков?

У **Компании #1** есть два счетчика. у одного поле `sent=3`, у другого `sent=2`, т.е. всего отправленных счетчиков 5.
У **Компании #2** - 1 счетчик. у него значение `sent=4`.

т.е. если сделать порядок по возрастанию, то должно получится так: `компания 2, компани 1`

Делаю как-то криво, вот так:

```sql
SELECT games.*, counters.game_id 
FROM games INNER JOIN counters 
ON games.id = counters.game_id 
GROUP BY counters.sent 
ORDER BY sum(counters.sent) asc
```

Comment: Сделайте минимальный пример https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example, и не забудьте указать что выводится сейчас и как должно быть - постараюсь помочь

Comment: Неполная группировка - на выходе можно получить любую хрень (хотя странно, что не сообщение об ошибке). Агрегируйте сначала суммы счётчиков в подзапросе, в потом уже связывайте с таблицей игр и сортируйте.